# React Router Nested Routes Working Locally but Failing on Live Deployment

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-router-dom

I'm facing an unexpected issue with React-Router that's puzzling me. I've set up routes in my application using the `createRoutesFromElements` function from `react-router-dom`. Everything works perfectly when I run the app locally, but as soon as I deploy it live, the nested routes start misbehaving.

Here's the snippet I'm using:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<MainLayout />}>
      <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
      <Route path="chat" element={<ChatLayout />}>
        <Route path={"messages"} element={<ChatList />} />
        <Route path={":chatId"} element={<ChatBox />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  )
);
```

To clarify, when I access routes like `http://localhost:3000/chat/messages`, everything works smoothly on my local machine. However, the situation takes a turn after deploying the app online. When I attempt to access the same routes or refresh the tab on the live site, such as `www.mysite.com/chat/messages`, I'm met with frustrating **404 not found issues**.

I tried setting up nested routes using `createRoutesFromElements`in React-Router. Expected smooth navigation on the live site, like on my local machine. However, I'm getting 404 errors when accessing routes directly or refreshing on the live site. Looking for help to resolve this.

Comment: The basic gist is that your server/hosting service needs to be configured to return/serve the root index.html file for all page requests into the app. Check the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to see if there's already a relevant section for your server/hosting service, otherwise you may need to consult their documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup some server-side routing to redirect all requests to the index.html file of your react app.

That way your react app can handle the routes.
The configuration steps might be different depending on your hosting service, in my case, my website was hosted in an Apache server, so I simply had to create an .htaccess file with the configuration required.

If you don't have access to your server configuration, you can use **createHashRouter** instead of **createBrowserRouter**. I'd suggest you to check the docs to [learn more about the HashRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/hash-router)